# How to auto align monitors in Windows 11?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11

On Windows 11, with this monitor configuration:

[image: display-layout]

I notice that sometimes upon reboot, system update, coming back from standby, or even after power cycling one of the monitors, Windows will "lose" my display alignment, or revert it to an "unaligned" configuration.

I use the word **aligned** to mean that the four monitors in a 2x2 configuration have no "gaps" between them in the logical (x,y) coordinates of the desktop.

**Every monitor in my configuration is 2560x1440.**

To illustrate what I mean, look at the layout of this monitor example in DisplayFusion's Monitor Configuration page.

[image: displayfusion]

Notice how the coordinates of the monitor are 0x1440 in the top left and 2560x2880 in the bottom right? That's correct if you do the math.

The "symptom" I see is that, seemingly randomly, they won't be aligned. The top-left of any given monitor might be, say, -8, or 12 -- indicating a misalignment in the horizontal direction. Or maybe it's misaligned in the vertical direction, and the y coordinate will be 1456, or if it's a top row monitor, it'll be -5 or 10 or something.

This causes programs that remember window position by desktop coordinates to go absolutely crazy, and I have to reconfigure them every time I launch them. It also makes mouse movement between the monitors very awkward: sometimes I'll hit the mouse against the "edge" of two monitors and it will not jump to the next monitor until I move the mouse away, and put it back on a different part of the monitor.

Is there a script, program or other technique to automatically detect and correct this situation?

BTW: DisplayFusion is not at fault. Uninstalling it doesn't help. In fact, the Windows Settings app seems *more* likely to cause misalignment than DisplayFusion. At least in DisplayFusion's Monitor Settings, it supports monitor "snapping" -- where I can just hold down left click on a monitor, and it will align it to a proper grid coordinate system.

Comment: I assume this didn’t happen on Windows 10? I can’t help myself from asking, has anyone else reported this issue, within the DisplayFusion community? Has DisplayFusion seen any Windows 11 specific updates?

Comment: I never had this monitor layout with so many monitors on W10, so I never had the symptom. Also, uninstalling DisplayFusion and rebooting doesn't help.

Comment: The only relevant feature could be the dynamic refresh rate with WDDM 3.0. Would be interesting to know if this even work on Windows 10.